# Port missing in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I wanted to install apache, php7, postgres12, node, java in ubuntu:18.04 base image dockerfile and wanted to show postgre data in php file. After building and running the container when I checked the process status, the port is missing. I started docker recently so I am new in this. Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# # Install openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN apt-get -y install nodejs



RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get -y install php7.2
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.2

RUN rm -f  /var/www/html/index.html
COPY . /var/www/html


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2 && apt-get install -y wget
Run wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12

USER postgres
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker

RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

EXPOSE 80 5432


CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

error

```
PS G:\Docker\test-docker-ubuntu-php\website> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
1fba1b8327fd        test-custom-all     "/usr/sbin/apache2ct…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                          test-custom
PS G:\Docker\test-docker-ubuntu-php\website> docker logs 1fba1b8327fd
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Can you help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: You almost always want to run these parts in separate containers; there are prebuilt images for `node`, `postgres`, `php` (with or without an attached Apache), and so on.  Trying to reduce this to a [mcve] will help you understand the actual issue; I expect you will get the same error if you remove the PHP setup.

Comment: I ran these parts in separate containers. Now I am trying to run all of them in one container and facing this problem. Can you help me out here?

Comment: You should go back to the working multiple-container setup; it's better practice in several ways.  (Do you want to restart your database and backend services, because you're fixing a small typo in your UI?  If you go to a clustered environment, you'll probably want exactly one database, a couple of front-end containers, and several back-end containers to keep up with load.)